# connecting records regarding their start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following records:

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| ID | StartDate        | EndDate         | Color |
+====+==================+=================+=======+
| 1  | 4/14/22 12:00 AM | 4/14/22 2:45 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | 4/14/22 3:40 AM  | 4/14/22 7:06 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | 4/14/22 7:06 AM  | 4/14/22 7:56 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | 4/14/22 7:56 AM  | 4/14/22 8:00 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | 4/14/22 7:56 AM  | 4/14/22 8:00 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 2  | 4/14/22 12:00 AM | 4/14/22 4:40 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 2  | 4/14/22 4:40 AM  | 4/14/22 6:00 AM | G     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 2  | 4/14/22 6:00 AM  | 4/14/22 8:00 AM | G     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

and I want to have an output to:
merge rows that are following each other (where prev.EndDate = cur.StartDate) if the colors are same.

the output should look like:

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| ID | StartDate        | EndDate         | Color |
+====+==================+=================+=======+
| 1  | 4/14/22 12:00 AM | 4/14/22 2:45 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1  | 4/14/22 3:40 AM  | 4/14/22 8:00 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 2  | 4/14/22 12:00 AM | 4/14/22 4:40 AM | R     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 2  | 4/14/22 4:40 AM  | 4/14/22 8:00 AM | G     |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

I tried with lead/lag and cte but couldn't manage. any ideas?

sample data:

```
declare @color table (
    ID int,
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime,
    Color char(1)
)

insert @color values (2707670, '2022-04-14 00:00:00.000','2022-04-14 02:45:00.000', 'R')
insert @color values (2707670, '2022-04-14 03:40:00.000','2022-04-14 07:06:28.977', 'R')
insert @color values (2707670, '2022-04-14 07:06:28.977','2022-04-14 07:56:25.600', 'R')
insert @color values (2707670, '2022-04-14 07:56:25.600','2022-04-14 08:00:00.000', 'R')
```

thank in advance.

Comment: Check out this article by Jeff Moden. It explains how to do this quite efficiently. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/group-islands-of-contiguous-dates-sql-spackle#:~:text=SQL%20Spackle%22%20is%20a%20collection,%22fill%20in%20the%20cracks%22.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I have checked but my problem is a bit more complex than that and I couldn't find a way to apply it to my problem.

Comment: @user3596006 - Yes... I agree.  This is actually a "Packing Intervals" problem  Itzik Ben-Gan has a remarkable article on the subject with code solutions and test data and the whole 9 yards at the following link.  https://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/